# Sql- Select command giving to mutch data

Tags: mysql, select

I am trying to get Data witht his SQL-Command, but it somehow returns the same data 3 times.

```
Select *, automarke from user join fahrzeuge
```

I dont really know why it is working that why, but it is handycapping my code quite a while. Does anybody know why the Select behaives that why?

Comment: any common column in those two tables i.e. user and fahrzeuge? It's just doing a cartesion product and hence multiple rows.

Comment: Also, `*, automarke` is a bit superfluous. The `*` already includes the `automarke`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify a condition on the join... Example :

```
select *, automarke from user join fahrzeuge on user.fahrzeuge_id = fahrzeuge.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Specify `condition` on which basis you want to fetch data. Otherwise, It will fetch all the data from the table `user` and `fahrzeuge`.

**Try something like this :**

```
select *, automarke from user join fahrzeuge on user.column_name = 'condition'
```